# HTTP Status 405 -The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I know this question has been asked here. but it seems something went wrong with me. I am simply posting form data to my controller I have jackson dependencies.but its throwing me the error HTTP status 405-request method not supported.

Here's my controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/addCompany",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public@ResponseBody String userLogin(HttpServletRequest req,@RequestBody CompanyRegVO user){
    logger.debug("signUp user:"+user);
     // get reCAPTCHA request param
    String gRecaptchaResponse = req.getParameter("g-recaptcha-response");
    boolean isVerified= Verify.verifyGcaptchResponse(gRecaptchaResponse);
    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString="";
}
```

this is my jquery I have used

```
home='<%=request.getContextPath()%>';
$('#userReg').submit(function(event){
    var add = {}
    add["type"] = $("#type").val();
    add["name"] = $("#companyName").val();
    add["regNumber"] = $("#regNumber").val();
    add["dob"] = $("#dob").val();
    add["email"] = $("#email").val();
    add["password"] = $("#password").val();
    add["confirmPassword"] = $("#cpassword").val();
    add["line1"] = $("#line1").val();
    add["line2"] = $("#line2").val();
    add["state"] = $("#state").val();
    add["country"] = $("#country").val();
    add["zipCode"] = $("#zipCode").val();
    console.log("search: ", add);
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
          headers: { 
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            },

        url : home+"/addCompany",
        data : JSON.stringify(add),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000,
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            alert(data)

        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            alert(e);

        },done : function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
        }
});
```

this is my CompnayRegVO

```
public class CompanyRegVO {
private String companyName;
private Integer regNumber;
private String password;
private String confirmPassword;
private String type;
private String email;
private String dob;
private Boolean enabled;
private AddressVO address;
//getters and setter
}
```

Edit 1;
Here's my POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>task</groupId>
    <artifactId>basicPages</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>basicPages Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>

    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Java.Net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--to send email -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- google recaptcha -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.tanesha.recaptcha4j/recaptcha4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.tanesha.recaptcha4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>recaptcha4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring framework START -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring framework END -->
        <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - START -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - END -->

        <!-- Jstl for jsp page -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP API -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL JDBC driver -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 3. logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- SQLServer JDBC driver (JTDS) -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>basicPages</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

this error is because of I have AddressVO object in my compnayRegVO but my json does not have address object??if yes please how to rectify it.

Comment: send a blank one then.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: Try sending a self made JSON to the server with a rest client/curl... and check if the server works, if it does it must be the client. After that try the debug console (network) and compare the diference (body+header) between both requests. Sending an empty JSON object is an easy way to test whether the request is processed by the right controller method.

Comment: @ST-DDT:I tried that I am getting 415- unsupported media type. I just passes **{ }** this only after that I tried with **{"type":"user"}**

Comment: In Ajax try delete this: `headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` and add this: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: I tried didn't work..:(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry All,
I have one stupidy that I have added method="POST" in my form. so it was taking that form posting so my service was not exposed using jquery.Now I have one doubt if someone tell me spring mvc bind the pages with url using internalResourceViewResolver. but is there any way I can do the same using jquery??